# How to remove bootstrap from angular 6 project completely?

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular6, angular7

I am trying to remove bootstrap from my angular 6 project so I can replace it with angular material. I tried running `npm uninstall bootstrap --no-save`, then in **app.module.ts**, I commented out the bootstrap line:

```
  ...
  exports: [],
  providers: [StudentService, EmailService, UploadFileService, StudentListComponent, EmailComponent, AddStudentComponent],
  // bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Finally, in **main.ts**, I commented out the bootstrap related line:

```
...
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}


// platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
//   .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Once this is done, I try to load my app, and I get no errors in the console, but the project is stuck on "loading" and no components appear. Any help on this would be awesome!

Comment: Put back bootstrap:[AppComponent]. It doesn't do anything with bootsrap.js

Comment: It's not an April's fool, i hope

Comment: And please read this page https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping

Answer (score 1):

Quick Answer:

The lines that you commented out are actually part of Angular, not the Bootstrap UI framework. I know the naming conventions can get confusion with so much going on, but you actually want to keep those in there. They're "boostrapping" the application together, not doing anything with `bootstrap`, if that makes sense.

You should be able to uncomment those lines and everything should work as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Angular does not use bootstrap (the CSS framework).
The line you commented out is an important part of the application.
From Wikipedia:
 In computing, a bootstrap loader is the first piece of code that runs when a machine starts, and is responsible for loading the rest of the operating system.

So `bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]` is just telling Angular to load that component first.

Comment: This was also correct, thanks for the response and info.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with bootstrap in AppComponent.ts and bootstrapModule in main.ts files, you need to just uninstall bootstrap from your project and install angular-material and reload the App!